# Running Gitlab-CI on project for two different Docker images

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

We have a small C++ project that is integrated on a local Gitlab installation. QA (a home-grown unit test via a shell-script with expected output) is done through `.gitlab-ci.yml` with a specific Docker image (`image: ubuntu:artful`). Due to subtle differences, we want to run the same tests also on `image: debian:stretch`, which requires of course small differences in the CI-config.

What I am currently doing is maintaining a separate branch with it's own `.gitlab-ci.yml`, which differs in the `image`-section, and small differences in the bodies of the different stages (different packages to `apt-get` etc.). That means I need to rebase `master` frequently into that branch, and make sure to manually merge changes to the ci-config.

This is not nice: in my previous life I used Jenkins, where I could easily maintain different CI-setups outside of the actual repo (I totally do get that GitLab solves the problem of having the CI-config itself under version control).

I think I could work around all the small differences in the gitlab-config between both branches with variables depending on the branch that I'm in, except for the docker image.

I see two different solutions to avoid maintaining those two branches just for CI purposes: 1) get the Gitlab-maintainers do install a VM with the required image instead, and register a specific additional runner, or 2) use a scheduled pipeline on the `master`-branch where I could pass in the image-name as a parameter.

Solution 1) seems the cleanest for me, but is out of my hands (and still requires special-casing/generalisation to variables inside the gitlab-ci config). Is there another way to run *multiple* gitlab-ci configurations in a *single* project without too much hassle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there's a third option but depending on the number of tests you have it may not be cleaner. Yaml supports [anchors](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#anchors) so you can define a template for each test and then do two instances of it. The pros include that both sets of test run in parallel in the same pipeline, the con is that it may get messy and pipeline will stop if one of them fails.

```
.job_template: &job_definition
  stage: test  
  services:
    - postgres
    - redis
  script:
    - run tests

test_a:
  <<: *job_definition
  image: ubuntu:artful
  variables:
     SOME_VAR: "override variable"

test_s:
  <<: *job_definition 
  image: debian:stretch
  before_script:
    - do some special preparations
```

Comment: Thanks Jakub, I'll try to play this through. The first hurdle is already that I can't really have two different `before_scripts` which is where you'd traditionally do `apt-get` etc, but I think I can work around it.

Comment: @ShiDoiSi You can have two different before_scripts, before_script in actual job overrides the one that's in the anchor.

Comment: Accepting this answer for now, because I learned two relevant things that solved my problem: anchors, and that I can actually have several image-tags (shudder). Thank you!